# How do you start QuickTime on the Mac?

Tags: macos, quicktime

I don't see QuickTime in my Applications folder but I thought it's installed on every Mac (I have a new Macbook Pro).

How do I start it?

Answer (score 4):

You should have "QuickTime Player" in your Applications folder. Try searching with Spotlight if you can't find it.